# Use ksoap2-android on Android too slow ?

Tags: wsdl, android-ksoap2

I have an android application acessing an webservice that returns a big result. 
I use **ksoap2-android 2.5.4**  to make a call soap webservice (wsdl).

My problem is, when I call it using ksoap2 on the android app, it takes a lot of time to process the result. As the result is a xml, how can I force the ksoap to give me an String result without process it into a SoapObject? Or there is another way to process the result more quickly?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue I would go with a binary format like AMF3 or ASN.1 or if the service is in Java too then just whatever DataOutputStream gives you...